# Multidex error when using ti.map and ti.goosh module

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I am making an Appcelerator Titanium application which use maps and notifications. To provide such functionality I want to use use:

- ti.map (official Appcelerator Titanium module for maps),
- [ti.goosh](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh).

The problem is that both requires Google Play Services and Appcelerator Titanium does not support multidex, so during compilation I always get an error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzd$zza$zza;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzg$zza;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzd;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzd$zza;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzg;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zze;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/playlog/internal/zza;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/playlog/internal/zzb;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/playlog/internal/zzd;
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[ERROR] :  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
[ERROR] :   ... 4 more
```

I was suggested that I should create my own .jar file with Google Play Services as described [here](https://medium.com/all-titanium/deal-with-titanium-modules-and-its-missing-support-for-android-multidex-546de5486d13#.15axfkq83).

Unfortunately I cannot manage to create proper proguard.conf file, so I always end up with similar error.

To be specific:

- I am able to create proguard.conf file (but it content must be wrong),
- I create .jar file and I switch it with original.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make it working is to create special version of SDK providing necessary functionality for both modules. It is described as [medium.com article](https://medium.com/all-titanium/deal-with-titanium-modules-and-its-missing-support-for-android-multidex-546de5486d13/) but it is really complicated matter.

Fortunately guys from caffeinalab provided [jar libraries](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/tree/master/gps-jars) with good description how to implement them.

If you still have any problem than it is good to check [this thread](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/issues/15) which can help you with common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most embarrassing situation (at least for me) countering multi-dexer issues. There are two ways you can feel helpful:

1. Try to create .jar libraries for both modules using same version of Google Play services (be aware of the further issues which can also require same versions)
2. If your only purpose is to support Maps & Push, then most best solution is to stick with the Titanium inbuilt CloudPush & Maps modules. (this is what I always prefer in most of my apps when I have to support Maps & Push together).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I added mine because it describes the first method more detailed.
The problem with CloudPush is that you need to pay monthly to send Push notifications from Appcelerator and you are stucked to their servers.

Comment: I don't think so that you will need to pay to Appcelerator.

If you are using the CloudPush module only to retrieve deviceToken and you have your own/other third party push server, then you can use Appcelerator module for free forever. They charge when you use their server to send Push messages.